Textlabels added to ggplot are not displayed

The following figure shows the frequency of publications over several years. I would like to add events to the upper part of the plot which took place during these years.
I tried the following code:
pub_over_year <- as_tibble(S$AnnualProduction) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Articles, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  labs(x = "Years", y = "Number of publications") +
  geom_text(aes(label= Articles), hjust= 0.5, vjust = -2, size= 3, color= "black") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_minimal()  +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob("event 1", rot = 90), 
                    xmin = 2010, xmax = 2010, ymin = 250) +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob("event 2", rot = 90), 
                    xmin = 2011, xmax = 2011, ymin = 250)
pub_over_year

I do not get an error message, but the text labels are not displayed.

You don't assign your updated plot to an object.  pub_over_year + annotation_custom(...) ... should be pub_over_year <- pub_over_year + annotation_custom(...) ....

Thank you, I corrected it in the code above.

It's better if you can include your data (or a sample of it). Using a little made-up data, the text labels are displayed okay with the code as-is. Are they outside the range of your data, e.g. changing ymin to 260 below will lose the "event 1" text.
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

tibble(Year = 2009:2012, Articles = 248:251) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Articles, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Years", y = "Number of publications") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Articles), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -2, size = 3, color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_minimal() +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob("event 1", rot = 90),
    xmin = 2010, xmax = 2010, ymin = 250
  ) +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob("event 2", rot = 90),
    xmin = 2011, xmax = 2011, ymin = 250
  )


Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0
